# CSS - having the same height on 2 different div in the same container

Tags: css, height

```
<body> 
    <div> 
        <div id="ROOT" > 
            <div id="ROOT_0" > 
                header  
            </div> 

            <div id="ROOT_1" > 
                <div id="ROOT_1_0>
                    Hi<br />
                    My<br />
                    Name<br />
                    Is<br />
                    Marco<br />
                </div

                <div id="ROOT_1_1>
                    I<br />
                    am<br />
                    Marco<br />
                </div>
            </div

            <div id="ROOT_2" > 
                footer
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

as you can see, ROOT_1_0 and ROOT_1_1 are in ROOT_1 but they have different height. Can i put the same height without using the height: attribute? cheers

Comment: Why don't you want to use the height attribute?  I'm assuming the issue is that you want them both to be the same height, and that height should be the minimum value required to hold the larger of the two entries.  If so, you will probably need to use height...

Comment: What browser(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and so on! I think all it's the right answer hehe:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should fix the bad markup (no closing quote in `id="ROOT_1_0>`, no closing greater than symbol on `</div`, et cetera) in your example HTML.

Second, I recommend specifying a min-height for both of your boxes in [em](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm)s.  Ems are relative to the font size of the current element, so they're expandable.  If IE6 is a concern, you can specify height and overflow: auto; for just IE6.

If ROOT_1_0 and ROOT_1_1 are supposed to be next to each other (say, by changing the width and floating them), consider using [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Comment: uhm. This will work only if use some image as background. But i use only background-color :(

Comment: uhm...i've resolved! Thanks to faux columns! And thanks to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't want to use `height`because you don't know how many pixels to fill in, but try `height: 100%`.

Comment: yeah, in fact i don't know how many pixels i must fill in. I tried to put height:100%; on ROOT_1_0 and ROOT_1_1 but it doesnt work :(